# Packaged and compiled application co-existence

Tags: file-roller

OS: Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit.

Since I have packaged version installed of the following application:

```
file-roller
```

which is Archive Manager, and I also have a compiled version installed, I would like to make sure the compiled one takes precedence.

I have 2 menu items named Archive Manager:

```
/usr/share/applications/file-roller.desktop
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop
```

One of which I can probably delete.

```
which file-roller
```

says:

```
/usr/local/bin/file-roller
```

which is my compiled version:

> ```
> file-roller 3.27.0, Copyright © 2001-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> ```

But there's still the packaged version:

> ```
> file-roller 3.16.5, Copyright © 2001-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> ```

It seems, that when I make a request in GUI for opening e.g. a ZIP file, the compiled version shows up, I would just like to make sure it will behave consistently.

I tried to uninstall the packaged version:

```
sudo apt-get purge file-roller
```

with result:

```
[sudo] password for vlastimil: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  librpm3 librpmio3 lzop rpm-common rpm2cpio
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  file-roller* mint-meta-cinnamon* nemo-fileroller*
The following held packages will be changed:
  file-roller
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 2,048 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

As you can see, it would remove:

```
mint-meta-cinnamon
```

and

```
nemo-fileroller
```

apart from the sole `file-roller`.

So I've put the package on hold until someone tells me how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the contents of the `.desktop` files, you’ll see that they don’t specify the path to the command to run. So they don’t affect precedence at all. The only aspect that matters here is the order of directories in your `PATH`, which should have `/usr/local/bin` ahead of `/usr/bin` anyway. (This explains the behaviour you’re seeing.)

Thus you can leave the package installed and still be sure your compiled version will be used instead.

If you want to avoid having two versions installed, you should either use `equivs` to build a fake `file-roller` package (avoiding the removal of packages depending on it), or build a newer version of the package yourself.